# jquery demo not working, how to?

Tags: jquery, resize, jsfiddle

i have this example found here: http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/demo/resize2

and i tried to reproduce it in [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/ubxYh/1/).

the way i did it is just by copying the code from the source view of the example, and the problem is that is not working.

the issue is that others examples from the same jquery plugin work fine in jsfiddle.

I also placed the example on a server but i get the same result.

this question might end up being a stupid one, but i am a bit confuse why it is working on the website and not in my try.

any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using jQuery > 1.6 and it seems this plugin is not compatible with jQuery 1.6 and above versions. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/ubxYh/2/), I only changed jQuery version to 1.5.2